# Recommendations for experiments that confirm Field Theoretic Models?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, phase-transition

In the introduction of Introduction to QFT by Peskin and Schroeder, the authors write:

> "we do not discuss the beautiful and varied experiments on phase transitions that led to the confirmation of field theory models.  We strongly encourage the student to read, in parallel with this text, a modern presentation of the experimental development of each of these fields".

Can anyone recommend such a presentation of the experimental development, hopefully up-to-date/modern for:

- condensed matter physics, phase transitions
- high energy physics
- etc

Comment: When it comes to phase transitions, the indisputable bible is Zinn-Justin's [Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena](https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Critical-Phenomena-International-Monographs/dp/0198509235).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform i may have not looked in depth enough, but it does not seem like that book reports experiment/observation, rather it builds theory

Comment: A modern representation of beautiful **phase transitions** can be found mostly in modern textbooks on condensed-matter field theory; e.g., Altland and Simons, “Condensed Matter Field Theory”, or Coleman, “Introduction to Many-Body Physics”.

I am not sure what OP means by “Modern Presentation of **Observations**”, since the quoted text refers to “phase transitions”. Perhaps an edit to the post is required.

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis no edit is required, I was hoping for a presentation of observations, but indeed the text I quoted was referencing phase transitions

Comment: @malxmusician212 : What do mean precisely by “observations”? Please elaborate further on that point.

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis summaries of experiments/justifications for the developments of theories. For example, summaries of the double slit experiment or the stern gerlach experiment to justify the necessity for quantum mechanics (as Townsend gives in his undergraduate textbook).

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis and/or experiments that confirm theories

Comment: @malxmusician212 : So you are looking for experiments which confirm quantum field theory? In which context; condensed matter or high-energy physics?

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis high energy, though condensed matter would be interesting as well

Answer (score 1):

Dedicated text books on field theory methods for statistical physics or condensed matter physics tend to be short on graphs that show real data. Often there is simply a table showing that critical exponents are predicted correctly.

Intro text books into condensed matter physics tend to have at least a few of these graphs, showing static and dynamic scaling, data collapse, etc. See, for example, chap 4 and 5 of Chaikin and Lubensky.

The most extensive compilation of data that I am aware of (in a text book) is Onuki, "Phase Transition Dynamics".

Answer (score 0):

Exist beautiful [Lectures on Statistical Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) by David Tong. There discussed some experimental evidences, but mostly it is about theoretical applications of qft in sft. But introduction chapter may create some first impression.